# Shimano gear cable adjuster barrel replacement

Tags: shifter

I have a hybrid-style bike with Shimano parts and I'd like to replace the gear cable "adjuster barrel" (?) on the shifter next to my front left brake, as I have mangled it by twisting it with a pair of pliers.

However, I'm not sure exactly what part I need to buy. This looks similar: http://www.halfords.com/cycling/parts/gears-drivetrain-cables/shimano-rd-7700-cable-adjuster-bolt-unit#tab3 ...but it says that it's for the rear derailleur rather than a front shifter, so I'm not sure if it's the right part. If not, could anyone tell me exactly which part I'd need to buy?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

They are same. But before spending money in it, it can be wise to check the threads in the shifter. If pliers used to twist it, the threads could deform, and new barrel will act the same.